# Start fragment from Service

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to make a Youtube video play on top of all activities so I used SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, Now I am stuck trying to start the YoutubeSupportFragment from the service, here is my onCreate method in the FloatingWindow Service

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(400,400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    parameters.x = 0;
    parameters.y = 0;
    parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

    linearLayout.addView(stop);
    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, parameters);


    linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = parameters;
        int x, y;
        float touchedX, touchedY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = updatedParameters.x;
                    y = updatedParameters.y;

                    touchedX = event.getRawX();
                    touchedY = event.getRawY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - touchedX));
                    updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - touchedY));

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(linearLayout, updatedParameters);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

And here is my XML file that I want displayed on as a floating window

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/COLOR_BACKGROUND">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.youtube.YoutubePlayerView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, on onCreate i tried inflating the linearLayout with the XML file, i'm getting a ClassNotFoundException for the fragment, i think its obvious since I didn't instantiate the fragment.

I also can't use FragmentTransaction to add the XML file to my linearLayout because i can't access FragmentManager from within the service class.

Any ideas how i can get the youtube player to play as a floating window??

This is what I'm trying to achieve
[image: Youtube floating window]

Comment: i know this is an old question, but did you make this work?(i'm also trying to make a floating youtube player)

Comment: @Guest1997 Yes I got it to work, but not using Video View, I instead switched to WebView. Wrote this code long time ago but its messy, I can give it to you, it works perfectly though, you just pass in youtube id to the service and everything else is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

in your service, start a new activity whose sole purpose would be to attach/display this fragment.
If you do not want multiple instances of this fragment/activity, make your activity as SingleTop in Manifest file